# Why is mingw 4.4 saying <random> needs c++0x?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

Why is it saying that other than the obvious answer.  Also how can I work around this, I don't want to add c++11 code to this project.

```
#include <random>
```

mingw 4.4 ( version that's shipped with QTSDK, not using QT Libraries though, just QT Creator )

This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming \
ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious answer? Do you have reason to believe the obvious answer isn't true?

Comment: I meant give details, not just "it needs c++0x".  Some people have given good answers, all I needed was rand/srand access.  I've been using <random> in vs for years now, didn't know it was part of the unfinished standard.  Problem solved thanks guys and gals!

Comment: @EddieV223: The standard was finished *last year*; that's why it's called C++11 now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<random>` header was only added to the c++ standard in C++0x. The standard library implementers put in a preprocessor directive to error out if you try to use `<random>` in C++98 mode, for one of two reasons:

If the header file takes advantage of new C++0x language features, it wouldn't work at all in the default C++98 mode. The C++0x error message is there so that you'd understand why it didn't work, rather than having to figure out the meaning of soup of "unknown keyword" and other error messages.

If the header file doesn't require any new C++0x language features, then the C++0x error message is there, so that you wouldn't accidentally use it thinking it was available in C++98. If you were to do that, and then somebody else tried to compile your code on a C++98-only compiler that didn't ship the `<random>` header at all (e.g. an older version of GCC that you intended to support by restricting yourself to C++98), they'd be quite mad.

Answer (score 5):

The `<random>` header only exists in C++0x (C++11 as it's called now).

If you want to generate random numbers without the new standard, you can include `<cstdlib>` and use the `rand()` function.

Note: Remember to `srand()` with something unique if you are using `rand()`, with let's say, the current time.

One more option: use `boost`, since C++11 standard library is mostly based on it. Switching to `boost` is trivial, but `boost` might be too large if this is a small project.

Comment: *"boost might be too large if this is a small project"* -- You don't have to use the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna work around C++11 you could use Boost's random libraries in place of C++11 although it may not be a 1to1 port, they both have the same functionality and are very similar. This solution would be much easier than rewriting all the random bits with C's outdated `rand` function
[see the boost random here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_random.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TR1 version of the random facilities although I wouldn't recommend it if you are at all allowed to use C++11.  The TR1 random facilities were changed substantially when the went into C++11.

I can say from personal experience that in gcc (libstdc++) the TR1 libraries are in deep maintenance mode.  Only std components get love.

If you must use C++98

```
#include <tr1/random>
...
   std::tr1::name_of_random_thing(...);
...
```